# Adding provisioning profiles manually in xcode 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

In `XCode 4`, when I downloaded the provisioning profiles from my developer account and double clicked on the provisioning profile, `XCode` opened and added the provisioning profile to the list of the valid profiles, but in XCode 5, it seems that the provisioning profile menu has been moved under `preferences -> accounts`.

So how can we add them manually with double click on them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As normal you can just double click. Once you have double clicked it will open up the `iPhone Configuration Utility` app and ask if you want `Add to Library` when you click `Add to Library` if you already have a provisioning profile with that name you will asked if you want to replace it just click `Replace Provisioning Profile` and you're done the new profile will appear in xcode.

If this isn't installed by default you can find the `iPhone Configuration Utility App` [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465) - **Thanks to @Dan for letting me know this link now is giving a 404**

So here is a link to the [`Apple Configurator`](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) that I believe has replaced the `iPhone Configuration Utility App`

[image: Add to Library]

Add to Library

[image: Replace provisioning profile]

Replace provisioning profile

Comment: thanks for your reply. But when I click on the provisioning nothing opens!!

Comment: @HuseinBehbudiRad See the addition of the link I have added to my answer.

Comment: It is now working. But it seems that the app is not same with xcode. Does adding provisioning to the library means that now xcode accept them as a valid provisioning?

Comment: The link for the iPhone Configuration Utility 404s.

Comment: @Dan thanks I have provided a link to the `Apple Configurator` which I believe has replaced the `iPhone Configuration Utility App`.

Answer (score -1):

check out this update apple document for your question. I am sorry if you already figured it out ! https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html

Comment: That is a seriously long document. Why should we be reading through it and where should we even be reading. Please add context to your answer instead of just saying read this.